# Embedding Power BI on Xamarin.Forms WebView

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, webview, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am having trouble embedding my **secured** report into my Xamarin.Forms app using a WebView. I understand that Power BI Embedded can be loaded into a web page via their JavaScript API. My logic was that this can be achieved in Xamarin.Forms through a WebView.

I have access to the Power BI embed token, embed URL, and report ID. My current method is to store a local HTML file with the required parameters for the JavaScript into a WebView to display the embedded report.

I use the following JavaScript to try to load the report into the local HTML:

```
<script>
    // Read embed application token from Model
    var accessToken = "<<ACCESS_TOKEN>>"

    // Read embed URL from Model
    var embedUrl = "<<EMBED_URL>>";

    // Read report Id from Model
    var embedReportId = "<<REPORT_ID>>";

    // Get models. models contains enums that can be used.
    var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

    var config = {
        type: 'report',
        tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
        accessToken: accessToken,
        embedUrl: embedUrl,
        id: embedReportId,
        permissions: models.Permissions.All,
        settings: {
            layoutType: models.LayoutType.MobilePortrait
        }
    };

    // Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
    var reportContainer = $('#reportContainer')[0];

    // Embed the report and display it within the div container.
    var report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);
</script>
```

All required JavaScript libraries are referenced in this snippet.

When the page has been initialized the WebView contains the HTML with the report not rendered in the assigned `<div>`. I suspect that the JavaScript to load the embedded report does not run in the Xamarin WebView.

Is it possible to embed **secured** reports in a Xamarin.Forms app? Is my approach the right way of achieving this? Or is there a better method to go about this?

Comment: What if you used an Azure web app to do essentially the same thing?  We've implemented the embedded approach as well and at the end of the day, it's just a URL so if you use something like NodeJS to implement the embedded logic, you should ultimately achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: Did you tried use embed reports? You can set the "Source" property of your webview with the embed report address. Example: http://myserver/reports/powerbi/Sales?rs:embed=true. 
Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/quickstart-embed#capturing-the-url-parameter

Comment: @BradDixon We have already made a web app and am familiar how to embed reports using your method. We are trying to make a native app for our solution using Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Yeah but that’s my point, it’s a duplication of code. You need to be online anyway so if you’ve already created a web app that does it, why not just reference that url?

Comment: Have you found solution to this? I'm having similar problem.